# Achieve blur-like glow effect in an specific object

Tags: rendering, texturing

I would like to learn how to make a kind of glow that looks good in well-illuminated environments, something like this. Any suggestions?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Apply an Emission shader to an object, move it on another render layer and in the compositor add a Glare node and set it to "Fog Glow".

Comment: I managed to do something similar following your advice of using different render layers, although I found that adding a Blur node in the compositor helped more to create the effect I was looking for. Thanks for the tip! :)